# getting checked checkbox out of grid

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have checkboxes at grid header row.

I wanted to find checkboxes which are clicked.

My check boxes are named as :

chk1 
chk2
chk3
chk4

chk is common and 1,2,3,4 gets increament per column.

To get checked box,i did following code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To gvSearch.Columns.Count - 1

IF CType(gvSearch.HeaderRow.FindControl("chk"& i+1 ,CheckBox).Checked)  THEN

'some logic

END IF

Next
```

But, `CType(gvSearch.HeaderRow.FindControl("chk"& i+1 ,CheckBox).Checked)`    is giving me error as:

```
Syntax error in cast operator;two arguments separated by comma are required.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brackets are placed incorrect

```
CType(gvSearch.HeaderRow.FindControl("chk"& i+1),CheckBox).Checked
```